# Multiple feeds from a single AC source

Tags: voltage, ac

Rather than have a line of plugs in a 3-gang extension on top of my kitchen cabinets, I thought that if I split the feed, then fuse and switch each power supply for each LED strip, it would be an ideal solution.

One feed to a 240 V AC to DC converter for a LED strip, one feed to a 24 V LED driver, and the other to a 12 V adaptor.

However, when I turn the switches off, the 240 V LED strip is still very dimly lit. I’ve checked the voltage for each feed and I’m getting 48 – 50 VAC on all three.

[image: Schematic]

Can anyone suggest a solution to this, please?

Hi ,
Thanks for all your replies. I've just rigged up a test harness and found that it is an induced voltage. I'm running a 2 core wire from the fuse box down to a 3 gang switch & then back to the adapters. When I replicate the length I'm getting 48 VAC . Seems a bit weird to get that kind of voltage but I can re-route everything to get round it. jsotola - the 240v LED is from the AC DC adapter (apologies for missing that out)

Comment: there is no 240 V LED strip in the diagram

Comment: what happens if you separate all of the circuits?

Comment: If you are getting 48-50V on each, then you are not connecting per the diagram. Or your "fuses" are not fuses.

Comment: It could be a slight induced voltage from nearby wiring, particularly since the neutral is shared. You might consider using a double-pole switch to also disconnect the neutral, and keep the neutral and live for the LED strip away from the other wires. 48-50 volts is very high for induced voltage though.

Comment: When you run neutral and live separately, the amount of magnetic field created is proportional to the area in between them.

Comment: This is likely capacitive coupling.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/567766/166672

Comment: Suggestions:1. Try  placing a 100k to 1M resistor across the input to each power supply . 2. Use 2PST to switch both feed lines to each power supply.